# Cursor (prompt) color using black background

Tags: color, stylesheet

I am dealing with a prompt (blinking cursor) color problem in Mathematica 12.3.0. I am using a black theme (my input cells have black background) and, during the cell editing, the prompt blinks in black, thus becoming invisible!

I’ve tried to work around with “Styles for Mathematica System-specific Elements” in the stylesheet and some “Option Inspector” stuff, but they only change the color of the cursor as it appears when the cell is not being edited (as saved or as executed), as soon I start to edit the cell, the cursor turn black again.

This is not a "mouse pointer" problem!!!!

Can any one please help?

Comment: I tried to recreate your problem by going to Format->Edit Stylesheet, then changing the `Input` styling to have gray text and a black background. My cursor still blinks on/off, but with "on" being white. You say that gray/black blink is horrible. How come? Are you looking for the cursor to blink between two visible colors instead of on/off? That appears to not be the behavior on every single textbox across multiple programs I just tried. They all blinked on/off. I'm also confused as to how the cursor exists in a cell if it's not being edited.

Comment: No no, just try that: go to Format ->Stylesheet -> ReverseColor. You will see that when you are edditing an input cell you will not be able to see the prompt at all. It blinks from transparent to black (thus invisible)!... After executing the cell it blinks from gray to transparent (that is OK)

Comment: Upgrade to 12.3.1.

Comment: It should be obvious, but let me state it anyway: Anytime you find a bug, the first thing to do is to check if you have the latest bugfix version. If not, upgrade. I am pretty sure bugfix versions are included in all licenses, i.e. if you have access to 12.3.0 then you also have access to 12.3.x.

Comment: I am using a institucional license (university). How can I update? My license server only offer 12.3.0 installation pack.

Comment: Douglas, contact your license manager.